# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser problem with split()

Tags: php, html, dom, parsing, split

I want to use the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) to display all my Left4Dead Steam achievements on my website. The achievements list on the steam community website looks something like this:

```
<img src="…" /><br />
<div class="achieveImgHolder"><img src="…" /></div>
<div class="achieveTxtHolder">
 <img src="…" />
 <div class="achieveTxt">
  <h3>Stand Tall</h3>
  <h5>Survive a campaign without being incapacitated.</h5>
 </div>
</div>
<br clear="left" />
```

Active achievements are separated from inactive achievements by

```
<br /><br /><br />
```

So I wrote the this code to display my achievements:

```
<?php
include("simple-html-dom-parser.php");
$achievementPage = file_get_html("http://steamcommunity.com/id/snorpey/stats/L4D?tab=achievements");
$activeInactiveSplit = split("<br /><br /><br />", $achievementPage);
$actives = str_get_html($activeInactiveSplit[0]);
$inactives = str_get_html($activeInactiveSplit[1]);

foreach($actives->find(".achieveTxtHolder") as $achievement)
{
 echo $achievement->find(".achieveTxt h3", 0)->innertext;
}
?>
```

I always get the following error and have no idea where comes from.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in testing.php on line 8

I tested the parser with another part of the page and it worked properly. It seems to have problems with splitting the page.

```
echo $actives // works w/out errors
```

What exactly went wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change...

```
$actives->find(".achieveTxtHolder", 0)
```

to...

```
$actives->find(".achieveTxtHolder")
```

Specifying 0 returns only the first occurrence instead of an iterable list of occurrences; since you're using a `foreach` you want all of the occurrences. Otherwise the `foreach` tries to iterate over something that's not a list, and thus your `$achievement` variable is actually NULL, hence why you get an error when you try to invoke `->find()` on it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I changed the script as you proposed, but it keeps running into the same error.

Comment: Have you tried dumping out the contents of `$activeInactiveSplit[0]` and `$activeInactiveSplit[1]` (via something like `print_r($activeInactiveSplit)` and seeing if they match your expectations? Likewise, try dumping out what you get back from your first `find()` call and see if it's what you expect.

Comment: @Snorpey and please click the check to accept Dav's answer, thx.

Comment: Patience Don, it doesn't seem like the issue is fully resolved yet. :)

Comment: @snorpey: What happens if you `print_r($actives->find(".achieveTxtHolder"))`?

Comment: print_r($activeInactiveSplit) returns an array. [0] contains the source code if the page before "<br /><br /><br />", [1] contains the rest. I still have no idea why $actives->find(".achieveTxtHolder") doesn't work as expected.

Comment: and print_r($actives->find(".achieveTxtHolder"))  produces "Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object ..."

Comment: Sounds like your find() call isn't actually finding anything. Are you sure you spelled the class name correctly, etc?